# Как реально удалить в git формально удаленные данные?

Tags: linux, git

Допустим, мы хотим взять какой-то проект и откатиться к его началу,
напрочь удалив все лишнее.

Казалось бы, что надо удалить все лишние ветки, обрезать оставленную и
может быть почистить мусор. Но не тут-то было, git не хочет просто так
ничего забывать, а просто делает вид, что информации уже не существует.

Делаем клон:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/avp210159/hello
avp@wubu:tmp$ cd hello
```

Поскольку я пользуюсь алиасами из [tutorial](https://githowto.com/ru/aliases), то выведу их  тут:

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git config -l
user.name=avp
user.email=avp210159@gmail.com
alias.co=checkout
alias.ci=commit
alias.st=status
alias.br=branch
alias.hist=log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
alias.histt=log --pretty=format:"%h T=%t %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
alias.type=cat-file -t
alias.dump=cat-file -p
core.editor=vi
avp@wubu:hello$
```

Запоминаем всю историю "проекта" с ее SHA

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git hist --all
*   80333c5 2016-06-20 | merge with pull origin (origin/mtime) [avp]
|\  
| * e86897b 2016-06-17 | mtime in branchmtime on avp-ubu1 [avp]
| * f028a44 2016-06-16 | Update README (local version) [avp]
| *   9a8ad84 2016-06-14 | fix README merge conflict [avp]
| |\  
| | * 6502c2b 2016-06-09 | new .mtimes filename and hook script + [avp]
| * | 54f9e11 2016-06-14 | change pre-commit description in README [avp]
| * | 2f6e07f 2016-06-09 | new .mtimes filename and hook script ++ [avp]
| |/  
| * 39f7393 2016-06-09 | new .mtimes filename and hook script [avp]
| * 7f9be15 2016-06-07 | add BRANCH= to Notes [avp]
| * 2c79116 2016-06-07 | restore mtimes in master [avp]
| * e572dc2 2016-06-07 | ya some  changes in Notes and mtimes script [avp]
| * 9430c0f 2016-06-07 | some changes in Notes and mtimes script [avp]
| * 33336a8 2016-06-07 | switch to style ... [avp]
| * c9d1277 2016-06-07 | delete .gittimes/ from .gitignore [avp]
| * 95bc9f3 2016-06-07 | mtimes pre-commit test2 [avp]
| * 4d74da9 2016-06-07 | mtimes pre-commit 1-st [avp]
| * a929ae6 2016-06-07 | delete .gitimes/, switch to pre-commit .mtimes [avp]
| * eeceb8b 2016-06-07 | mtimes in pre-commit (initial test 2 (--amend)) [avp]
| * e0debec 2016-06-06 | mtimes sentinel again 3-nd [avp]
| * bb90a66 2016-06-06 | mtimes sentinel again 2-nd [avp]
| * b8658c0 2016-06-06 | mtimes sentinel again [avp]
| * 4a1df91 2016-06-06 | mtimes sentinel 3-st [avp]
| * fd787f2 2016-06-06 | mtimes with sentinel 2-nd () [avp]
| * f0463c9 2016-06-06 | mtimes with sentinel 1-st [avp]
| * 66be459 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit ./gitimes +n-th mistake [avp]
| * 20c41f6 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit ./gitimes +n-th [avp]
| * e9606f8 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit ./gitimes n-th [avp]
| * 204f16f 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit ./gitimes [avp]
| * 44956af 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit 5-th [avp]
| * 114cf75 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit 4-th [avp]
| * 81ddd75 2016-06-03 | mtime with nested commit in postcommit 2-nd [avp]
| * 1cc0c8a 2016-06-03 | mtime with nested commit in postcommit 2-nd [avp]
| * a59abd9 2016-06-03 | mtime with nested commit in postcommit [avp]
| * 312e92b 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit 3 4 [avp]
| * a54cd63 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit 3 [avp]
| * a1aee23 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit 2 [avp]
* | 3c4de65 2016-06-20 | ya commit [avp]
* | 307bd84 2016-06-20 | delete .gitimes/... again (was restored at play with history) [avp]
* | ce922e3 2016-06-20 | rebase ... try delete a lot of histiry ... [avp]
* | 2f7aecd 2016-06-14 | change pre-commit description in README [avp]
* | 0dd8e2a 2016-06-09 | new .mtimes filename and hook script ++ [avp]
* | 88c5a7d 2016-06-03 | mtime with nested commit in postcommit 2-nd [avp]
* | 6ddf211 2016-06-03 | mtime with nested commit in postcommit 2-nd [avp]
* | a78f31e 2016-06-03 | mtime postcommit 2 [avp]
|/  
* a31734c 2016-06-02 | mtime work begins [avp]
| *   f80dd69 2016-06-20 | Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/avp210159/hello (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) [avp]
| |\  
| | * eb0216f 2016-06-17 | mtime on avp-ubu1 [avp]
| * | 3e24a50 2016-06-20 | update a bit Git-Notes master version [avp]
| |/  
| * a06157e 2016-06-16 | Change README (local master version refer to mtime README) [avp]
| * 1e15bc5 2016-06-16 | make mtime branch, restore README & Notes from it [avp]
|/  
* d4aaa79 2016-05-26 | try .md formatting in README [avp]
* b9db73c 2016-05-25 | github push from home OK [Vasily]
* 1ff513c 2016-05-25 | change Git-Notes, try PUSH! [avp]
* b6a9482 2016-05-25 | change readme, try to pull changes after clone [avp]
* f7ae83c 2016-05-25 | hide email [Vasily]
* eeac95f 2016-05-25 | add .gitignore ~/.gitconfig as my-home-... [avp]
* 566eb66 2016-05-25 | add can do/can't do in Git-Notes [avp]
* 213ddd5 2016-05-25 | add README.md for git [avp]
* 4e2c742 2016-05-25 | result of curl in Git-Notes [avp]
* 57953e4 2016-05-25 | add Git-Notes file [avp]
| * 2d6f376 2016-06-17 | mtimes on style avp-ubu1 (origin/style) [avp]
| * e312891 2016-06-16 | Update README.md [Vasily]
| * d8fb896 2016-06-16 | test .md ref to other file in github in README [avp]
| * ae6d0e1 2016-06-14 | Create README in this branch [Vasily]
| * a13af39 2016-06-14 | in style mtimes on too [avp]
| * 56494cb 2016-06-07 | some changes in .mtimes pre-commit [avp]
| * 1a0adf6 2016-06-07 | add .gitignore from master [avp]
| * e466e8c 2016-05-24 | Updated index.html [avp]
| * c17f477 2016-05-24 | Hello uses style.css [avp]
| * 0bfa599 2016-05-24 | Added css stylesheet [avp]
|/  
* 8a6023f 2016-05-24 | Added index.html. [avp]
* a828998 2016-05-24 | Moved hello.html to lib [avp]
* ba52194 2016-05-24 | Add author/email [avp]
* f9de6a7 2016-05-20 | Added HTML header (tag: v1) [avp]
* 8d54403 2016-05-20 | Added standard HTML page tags (tag: v1-beta) [avp]
* 05bb38e 2016-05-20 | Edit <h1> tag [avp]
* a7da921 2016-05-20 | First Commit [avp]
avp@wubu:hello$
```

Смотрим состояние

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git st
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
avp@wubu:hello$ git br
* master
```

и отсоединяемся от удаленного репозитория

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git remote rm origin
```

Снова смотрим историю (теперь уже видна только master ветка)

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git hist --all
*   f80dd69 2016-06-20 | Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/avp210159/hello (HEAD -> master) [avp]
|\  
| * eb0216f 2016-06-17 | mtime on avp-ubu1 [avp]
* | 3e24a50 2016-06-20 | update a bit Git-Notes master version [avp]
|/  
* a06157e 2016-06-16 | Change README (local master version refer to mtime README) [avp]
* 1e15bc5 2016-06-16 | make mtime branch, restore README & Notes from it [avp]
* d4aaa79 2016-05-26 | try .md formatting in README [avp]
* b9db73c 2016-05-25 | github push from home OK [Vasily]
* 1ff513c 2016-05-25 | change Git-Notes, try PUSH! [avp]
* b6a9482 2016-05-25 | change readme, try to pull changes after clone [avp]
* f7ae83c 2016-05-25 | hide email [Vasily]
* eeac95f 2016-05-25 | add .gitignore ~/.gitconfig as my-home-... [avp]
* 566eb66 2016-05-25 | add can do/can't do in Git-Notes [avp]
* 213ddd5 2016-05-25 | add README.md for git [avp]
* 4e2c742 2016-05-25 | result of curl in Git-Notes [avp]
* 57953e4 2016-05-25 | add Git-Notes file [avp]
* 8a6023f 2016-05-24 | Added index.html. [avp]
* a828998 2016-05-24 | Moved hello.html to lib [avp]
* ba52194 2016-05-24 | Add author/email [avp]
* f9de6a7 2016-05-20 | Added HTML header (tag: v1) [avp]
* 8d54403 2016-05-20 | Added standard HTML page tags (tag: v1-beta) [avp]
* 05bb38e 2016-05-20 | Edit <h1> tag [avp]
* a7da921 2016-05-20 | First Commit [avp]
avp@wubu:hello$
```

Уходим куда-то к началу наших забав:

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git reset --hard 8a6023f
HEAD is now at 8a6023f Added index.html.
avp@wubu:hello$ 
avp@wubu:hello$ git br
* master
avp@wubu:hello$ git st
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
avp@wubu:hello$ ll
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  4 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:53 ./
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 16384 Jun 23 15:50 ../
drwxrwxr-x  8 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:54 .git/
-rw-rw-r--  1 avp  avp     95 Jun 23 15:50 index.html
drwxrwxr-x  2 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:50 lib/
```

На всякий случай "почистим" и видим:

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git gc
Counting objects: 69, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
Writing objects: 100% (69/69), done.
Total 69 (delta 25), reused 65 (delta 24)
avp@wubu:hello$ git hist --all
* 8a6023f 2016-05-24 | Added index.html. (HEAD -> master) [avp]
* a828998 2016-05-24 | Moved hello.html to lib [avp]
* ba52194 2016-05-24 | Add author/email [avp]
* f9de6a7 2016-05-20 | Added HTML header (tag: v1) [avp]
* 8d54403 2016-05-20 | Added standard HTML page tags (tag: v1-beta) [avp]
* 05bb38e 2016-05-20 | Edit <h1> tag [avp]
* a7da921 2016-05-20 | First Commit [avp]
avp@wubu:hello$
```

что все вроде бы ОК.

Но, что если посмотреть на запомненные SHA и ...

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git co e86897b
Note: checking out 'e86897b'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at e86897b... mtime in branchmtime on avp-ubu1
avp@wubu:hello$ ll
total 64
drwxrwxr-x  4 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:57 ./
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 16384 Jun 23 15:50 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 avp  avp    440 Jun 23 15:57 .cur-mtimes-avp-ubu1-avp*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 avp  avp    379 Jun 23 15:57 .cur-mtimes-wubu-avp*
drwxrwxr-x  8 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:57 .git/
-rw-rw-r--  1 avp  avp     17 Jun 23 15:57 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 avp  avp  10980 Jun 23 15:57 Git-Notes
-rw-rw-r--  1 avp  avp     95 Jun 23 15:50 index.html
drwxrwxr-x  2 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:57 lib/
-rw-rw-r--  1 avp  avp    327 Jun 23 15:57 my-home-.gitconfig
-rw-rw-r--  1 avp  avp   1054 Jun 23 15:57 README.md
avp@wubu:hello$ git br
* (HEAD detached at e86897b)
  master
avp@wubu:hello$ git st
HEAD detached at e86897b
nothing to commit, working directory clean
avp@wubu:hello$ tail README.md 

echo \#$(date) WD:$(pwd)  \($BRANCH $(git rev-parse HEAD)\) > $MTIMES
cat $TNEW >> $MTIMES
chmod +x $MTIMES
rm -f $TNEW 
git add $MTIMES

</pre>

it's mtime branch README
avp@wubu:hello$ cat .cur-mtimes-wubu-avp 
#Thu Jun 16 16:11:00 MSK 2016 WD:/home/avp/src/git_tutorial/work/hello (## mtime 9a8ad84f9a085333d05051600dee9d412ad9c7f5)
touch -m -t 201606071534.57 '.gitignore'
touch -m -t 201606071523.21 'Git-Notes'
touch -m -t 201606161610.04 'README.md'
touch -m -t 201606021438.31 'index.html'
touch -m -t 201606031443.13 'lib/hello.html'
touch -m -t 201606021438.31 'my-home-.gitconfig'
avp@wubu:hello$
```

классно... (а ведь хотели-то все лишнее удалить). Кстати, обратите внимание,
что мы видим удаленную ветку mtime, а вовсе не удаленную уже часть оставленной
ветки master.

Затем возвращаемся назад:

```
avp@wubu:hello$ git co master 
Warning: you are leaving 46 commits behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  e86897b mtime in branchmtime on avp-ubu1
  f028a44 Update README (local version)
  9a8ad84 fix README merge conflict
  54f9e11 change pre-commit description in README
 ... and 42 more.

If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> e86897b

Switched to branch 'master'
avp@wubu:hello$ ll
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  4 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:59 ./
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 16384 Jun 23 15:58 ../
drwxrwxr-x  8 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:59 .git/
-rw-rw-r--  1 avp  avp     95 Jun 23 15:50 index.html
drwxrwxr-x  2 avp  avp   4096 Jun 23 15:59 lib/
avp@wubu:hello$
```

и опять наслаждаемся самообманом.

Каким образом, не воссоздавая по шагам в новом каталоге новую историю, можно
откатить клон, реально удалив все не нужное?
(да, я знаю о существовании [git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), которая все же позволяет
Rewrite branches, но как-то это у них сложновато выглядит...).

Comment: git gc ничего не почистил. А это значит, что где то осталась ссылка на коммит. `git branch -a` и `git tag --list` ничего лишнего не показывают?

Comment: Почистить reflog: `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all; git gc --prune=now`. После этого сделать чекаут на e86897b уже не получится.

Comment: @KoVadim, branch -- только master, а пара тегов есть, но они и должны быть в оставленной истории (они в самых первых коммитах)

Comment: я пока соглашусь с @kmv - нужно ещё и reflog проверять.

Comment: @kmv, точно. Эти волшебные слова сработали. Оформите, пожалуйста, ответом.

Comment: @KoVadim, совет kmv сработал. Т.е. ссылки висели откуда-то из лога. Но все равно -- ...ацкая система. Как чистить середину -- не представляю.

Comment: середину - в смысле коммиты в середине дерева?

Comment: @KoVadim, да. Например, хочу удалить десяток коммитов из середины ветки (и память чтобы освободилась). Т.е. достаточно после rebase -i сделать то же самое с reflog?

Comment: просто так удалить коммиты с середины нельзя. Но можно сделать rebase,  а он умеет удалять. Правда, возможно придется решать конфликты. А ещё rebase умеет делать сквош - сливать несклько коммитов в один. Вполне возможно, что это то, что Вы ищете.

Comment: Удалить десяток коммитов - значит удалить внесенные в них изменения. Если вы хотите сэкономить место, то лучше сквош через `rebase -i`, как выше KoVadim  порекомендовал.

Comment: @KoVadim, не понимаю, почему нельзя? Ну, раз нельзя, то сквош (вместе с git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all; git gc --prune=now) я завтра попробую (посмотрю, исчезнут ли версии файлов)

Comment: просто удалить коммиты с середины нельзя. rebase при удалении коммитов перестраивает все последующие. То есть, после rebase хеш для веток обычно меняются.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Говоря упрощенно, `git gc` удаляет устаревшие недостижимые объекты. По-умолчанию, недостижимый объект устаревает через 2 недели. Объект не достижим, если:

- Он не входит коммиты некоторой ветки (после сброса ветки master объекты "вверх" по истории стали недостижимыми)
- На него нет ссылок из [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). В данном случае, reflog содержит ссылку на f80dd69, появившуюся после клонирования, - она и препятствует очистке.

Поэтому сначала удалим из reflog записи с недостижимыми (в смысле истории веток) объектами:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
```

Затем удалим мусор, считая недостижимые объекты уже устаревшими, не дожидаясь двух недель:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: Спасибо, про ссылки из reflog я только сейчас узнал.

Answer (score 5):

Если нужно удалить все коммиты, недоступные из оставшихся веток - есть радикальный способ:

```
cd ..
git clone hello hello2
rm -R hello
mv hello2 hello
cd hello
```

Рефлоги и недоступные объекты в клон не попадут.

Если нужно почистить всю историю коммитов, оставив только текущий - есть еще более радикальный способ:

```
rm -R .git
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Ну а способ с явной очисткой рефлога вам уже сказали.

Comment: Ага, клон и move -- и gc не нужно? Тоже интересно. А вот второй способ только для одной ветки годится.

Comment: @avp не для *одной ветки* - а для *одного коммита*. Это способ намеренно похерить всю историю.