# Поменять у автора и коммитера емейл и имя во всех коммитах

Tags: git

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [Change the author and committer name
>   and e-mail of multiple commits in
>   Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/5752652)

Я обнаружил, что в моём репозитории некоторые коммиты были сделаны под пользователем root.

Можно ли как-то исправить имя автора и емейл во всех "неправильных" коммитах?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/5752652

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы изменить автора (или коммитера) вам понадобится переписать всю историю репозитория, начиная с первого коммита этого автора.

Если вы согласны с этим (во многих командах избегают переписывания истории), то вы можете поправить историю при помощи [git filter-branch](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-filter-branch.html).

Страницы описания включают несколько примеров с которых вы можете начать.

Конкретно, вы можете поправить неправильные имена авторов и их емейлы для **всех веток и всех тегов** при помощи данной команды (источник: [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/)):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Обратите внимание: хотя скрипт написан на sh, но его можно выполнить и под windows в случае если у вас установлен git. Для этого сначала в папке репозитория выберите `git bash here`, а потом запустите скрипт командой `sh <имя файла скрипта.sh>`.

Также если вам необходимо полностью удалить старые данные, то вы можете воспользоваться информацией из этого вопроса: [Как реально удалить в git формально удаленные данные?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/537951/213987)