# Откат коммитов в гит-проекте после переписания истории. Дубли в bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

*Извините. Автор понимает, что он "ух идиот, как так вообще можно, убери руки от клавиатуры, не трогай больше ее".*

Был проект, отслеживаемый git-ом, залитый на bitbucket (наверное, это неважно).
В какой-то момент мне захотелось поменять имена автора у большого количества коммитов. Для этого воспользовался командой [отсюда](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email), не прочитав предупреждение.
Команда:

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter '
WRONG_EMAIL="wrong@example.com"
NEW_NAME="New Name Value"
NEW_EMAIL="correct@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Далее были сделаны самые ужасные вещи, которые я мог сделать, а именно:
`git fetch`, `git pull`, `git push`.

Теперь в битбакете каждый мой коммит теперь дублируется (но уже с измененным именем).

Именно, вопрос: возможно ли вернуть все обратно? Я понимаю, что "переписал историю", но, похоже, не понимаю, что это очень опасно.

Comment: Осторожней когда пишете команды в консоле =) Пишите

Comment: Я [пользуюсь этим же скриптом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/763153/213987) в git'е. Вам надо было сразу после переписывания истории сделать  `git push --force`. Дополните вопрос: что показывает `git status` и `git reflog`? Думаю, что можно сделать `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` + `git push --force`, но вы сначала лучше сделайте копию папки проекта и покажите вывод команд. А то легко можно ещё больше усугубить ситуацию.

Comment: Коммиты, которые продублированные, они абсолютно идентичные? Или у них разные идентификаторы?

Comment: Пишите git reflog, ищите хэш вашего pull`a и push`a. Потом пишете например git reset --hard a0d3fe6, где --hard a0d3fe6 -- хэш вашего действия, чтобы его откатить, (после выполнения, вы потеряете все локальные изменения из этого коммита). Сделайте копию локального  репозитория на  всякий случай прежде чем всё это проделывать.

Comment: @Алексей, у них разные хэши, разные авторы

Comment: @Dmitriy, все действия происходили в новой ветке, поэтому я принял решение удалить ее и переписать все заново

Comment: @AK, все действия происходили в новой ветке, поэтому я принял решение удалить ее и переписать все заново