# Теряется коммит при создании ветки без названия (dangling commit)

Tags: git

У меня есть последовательность коммитов

```
A---B---C---D (HEAD) (master)
```

Далее я перехожу в коммит A

```
A (HEAD) ---B---C---D (master)
```

Вношу некоторые изменения и делаю новую ветку, путём создания нового коммита:

```
A---B---C---D (master)
|----------------------------- E (HEAD)
```

После этого перехожу в D:

```
A---B---C---D (HEAD) (master)
|----------------------------- E
```

Но отобразить `E` никакими мыслимыми способами не получается. Пробовал

```
git branch 
git log --graph
git log --branches
```

---

## Добавлено

Пример действий

```
$ git checkout <A>
$ touch 1.txt
$ git commit -am "new not a name branch"
$ git checkout master
```

Далее смотрю список комитов. Коммита `<E>` нет.

Comment: Приведите команды, которыми вы выполняли эти переходы между состояниями.

Comment: @D-side добавил

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Это нештатная ситуация

У вас это была не "ветка без названия", а "отделённая голова" (и это не едкая шутка, а буквальный перевод термина ["detached `HEAD`"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head)).

`E` считается ["коммитом-потеряшкой"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/505118/181100) (dangling commit), поскольку не связан ни с какой веткой или меткой и будет через какое-то время (`gc.reflogExpireUnreachable`, [по умолчанию через 30 дней](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#_configuration)) **стёрт** сборщиком мусора (`git gc`) окончательно.

Поэтому никакие *обычные* средства работы вам его не покажут, да. На уровне пользователя можно считать, что этого коммита больше нет.
Придётся использовать *аварийные* низкоуровневые средства. Например, `git reflog`.

А чтобы он перестал быть "потеряшкой", необходимо зафиксировать его, сделав на нём (или впереди него, если у вас есть коммиты на нём основанные) ветку или метку.

Например, найдя в `git reflog` ваш потерянный коммит, можно разместить на нём ветку:

```
git checkout HEAD@{число} # или сразу хэш, как вам проще
git checkout -b название-ветки
```

Comment: Как сделать впереди него ветку (зафиксировать его)?

Comment: Пробовал вызывать `git gc --force`, когда находился в мастере при уже созданном `<E>`, но после этого всё равно удалось перейти в `<E>`

Comment: @hedgehogues потому что рефлог на него ссылкется, рефлоги gc не чистит

Comment: @PavelMayorov а смысл тогда в `git gc`?

Comment: @hedgehogues рефлог не бесконечен.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, т.е в случае если `reflog` больше не содержит `<E>`, то `git gc` удалит *dangling commit*?

Comment: @D-side зачем две команды checkout когда это делается одной?

Comment: @PavelMayorov в гите очень многое делается многими способами, в том числе "одной командой". Я в ежедневном обиходе использую довольно небольшое подмножество команд, просто чтобы не держать до фига в голове :)

Comment: @hedgehogues`gc` удаляет только устаревшие коммиты https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537951/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-git-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @D-side но ведь вы уже знаете эту команду! Что сложного в `git checkout HEAD@{число} -b название-ветки`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov то, что этой формой я почти никогда не пользуюсь и мне нужно открыть маны, чтобы составить команду. А вот "перейти на коммит Х" и "разместить на HEAD новую ветку" пользуюсь регулярно.

Comment: @D-side это одна и та же форма, просто разные наборы опциональных параметров...

Comment: @PavelMayorov я в голове рассматриваю их как разные формы, поскольку они делают существенно разные вещи (открыть vs. создать). Это мои собственные тараканы.

Comment: @D-side вы забыли что у настройки reflogExpireUnreachable другое значение по умолчанию, такие рефлоги устаревают быстрее

Comment: @PavelMayorov точно. Другая опция. Спасибо.